# Location of Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-studio

I have two business units. We want the results of this journey to populate back to SF so I’m moving the Data Extension being used to the Salesforce Data Extensions folder. However, the automation lives in the other business unit, therefore when I select the Data Extension to have the automation to output to, it shows the Salesforce Data Extension folder, but none of the info from the other business unit.

I see there is a Shared Salesforce Data Extension folder however in Contact Builder and Email Studios I do not have an option to move that Data Extension to it.

I can recreate the automation in the proper business unit, however, I’m generally curious now if you can put Data Extensions in that Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder.

Thanks!